# Creating csv file with PHP, save in temp, and upload via API

Tags: php, csv

I'm using the following code based on the Mailchimp API [documentation](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list.func.php) to create a CSV of all the members of a certain list.

```
session_start();
$apikey= $_SESSION["api_key"];
$list_id = $_POST['list_id'];
$chunk_size = 4096; //in bytes
$url = 'http://us1.api.mailchimp.com/export/1.0/list?apikey='.$apikey.'&id='.$list_id;
$handle = @fopen($url,'r');
$csvOutput = "";
if (!$handle) {
  echo "failed to access url\n";
} else {
  $i = 0;
  $header = array();
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, $chunk_size);
    if (trim($buffer)!=''){
      $obj = json_decode($buffer);
      if ($i==0){
        $header = $obj;
      } else {
        $csvOutput .= $obj[0]."\n";
      }
      $i++;
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
$filename = "list-".$list_id.".csv";
file_put_contents($filename, $csvOutput);

}
```

If I run this entirely locally, it works perfectly and generates a CSV in the same directory as the PHP file above. However, when I run this on my server, it completes without error, but I can't find where the file is actually stored. I know that the `$apikey` and `$list_id` are coming through okay. I'm thinking there might be a directory permission issue that's preventing the file from saving.

To further this, I really don't want to store the file on my server. I actually want to take this file that's generated and immediately upload it to Box.com using their API. I can run the following code on its own and the file uploads perfectly. I'm just not sure how to combine the two.

```
$headr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $target_url = 'https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content';
    $file_name_with_full_path = realpath('better.jpg');//this needs to be the file that was generated with the above PHP
    $post = array('parent' => '4224475591','file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
 $json = json_encode(array(
                                'name' => 'myfile', 
                                'parent' => array('id' => 4224475591)
                            ));
        $fields = array(
                      'attributes' => $json,
                      'file'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path
                  );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $result;
```

So, the full question is how I combine these two PHP files together to generate the CSV and immediately upload to Box? I'm fine if the file is saved temporarily and then deleted or similar.

Comment: since your `$filename` doesn't have any path information, it'll be created in whatever directory `getcwd()` tells you, which usually will be the directory that the parent/controlling script was fired up in.

Comment: Not familiar with `getcwd()` where does this come from and how can I change it? I changed the code so that I save the file in a directory other than where the file is, but it's not working on my server, but it is working locally.

Comment: http://php.net/getcwd

Comment: @MarcB Thanks.  I changed the code so that I save the file in a directory other than where the file is, but it's not working on my server, but it is working locally

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a absolute path on your server. Something like this:

```
$filename = "/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/list-".$list_id.".csv";
```

The second script you could run as a cron job although once the file is created there should be no problem in using your curl function then all in one script.

Comment: I figured this out right before your post, so now I'm saving in a different directory. This works when I run it all locally, but not when I run on my server. The code executes without error, but the file isn't in the directory where I'd expect.